# How is JavaScript Date object aware of Daylight Saving Time?

Tags: javascript, timezone

I'm based in London, and I noticed when I do the following in Chrome console:

```
> new Date(2019, 01, 01)
< Fri Feb 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)

> new Date(2019, 03, 01)
< Mon Apr 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
```

I assume JS somehow takes the locale information from my system setting. But my question is how is JS in addition know if a time in my locale is observing DST or not (here the GMT/BST).

As a further step, can I construct two date objects and manually passing in the timezone loacle (say, American/Los_Angeles), and I want JS to tell me if it's observing PDT or not?

Comment: Your computer is very aware of timezones and DST (it changes properly twice a year, doesn't it?), so why shouldn't JS be aware of this too?

Comment: It's interesting, does JS actually has a built-in set of rules specifying one country's DST starts on the second Sunday of March? Because potentially there're loads of DST shifts around the world, and each country can change its law for DST, how does JS cope with this change? Besides, does JS expose this DST information, and can I manually set a timezone to let JS determine if DST is observed?

Comment: There are databases maintained for timezone information, and modern OSs and/or browsers auto-update them regularly from the internet…

Comment: Getting the default locale from your system is implementation dependent (meaning that not all browsers handle it the same way). From there, the recommendation is that browsers use the [IANA Time Zone Database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) to determine UTC offset, DST, etc.